# what is pep 8? How does it help in programming? What are the set of rules regarding that?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, pep8, pep

what is the Full form and what it is used for?

I was going through basics of python when I came across this term. what does it mean by maximum readability?

Comment: You should not ask questions without [doing any research](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) yourself.

Answer (score 1):

**Actually [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) is a document with some best practices in Python.** 
It helps us to improve readability and that's why it's so important.

**“Code is read much more often than it is written.”** 
Once you’ve written it, you’re never going to write it again. But you’ll definitely have to read it again. So, you should understand it even after a long time passed. Furthermore, other people should be able to read and understand what's going on in your code.
Actually, that's it.

**Nowadays, there are different PEPs, but all of them have one purpose.**
Moreover there is a simple guide about [Zen Of Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/) :)